# Supervisor doesn't kill flask application

Tags: python, flask, supervisord

I have the following conf file for supervisord:

```
[program:backend]
command=../../../venv/bin/python backend.py

[program:celeryd]
command=../../../venv/bin/celery worker --app=tasks -l debug

[program:memcached]
command=memcached
```

my backend.py is a pretty standard flask app with debug=True. It's not daemonized (running python backend.py in the console doesn't return the prompt)

when I execute `supervisord`, I see the following prompt:

```
[venv] supervisor$ supervisord
2013-05-08 18:42:22,148 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2013-05-08 18:42:22,148 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2013-05-08 18:42:22,149 INFO supervisord started with pid 6778
2013-05-08 18:42:23,152 INFO spawned: 'celeryd' with pid 6781
2013-05-08 18:42:23,156 INFO spawned: 'memcached' with pid 6782
2013-05-08 18:42:23,159 INFO spawned: 'backend' with pid 6783
2013-05-08 18:42:24,314 INFO success: celeryd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2013-05-08 18:42:24,314 INFO success: memcached entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2013-05-08 18:42:24,314 INFO success: backend entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

This is what pstree looks like:

```
 | | \-+= 91117 vng -/bin/bash
 | |   \-+= 06778 vng /Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/venv/bin/python /Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/venv/bin/supervisord
 | |     |-+= 06781 vng /Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/venv/bin/python ../../../venv/bin/celery worker --app=tasks -l debug
 | |     | |--- 06795 vng /Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/venv/bin/python ../../../venv/bin/celery worker --app=tasks -l debug
 | |     | |--- 06796 vng /Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/venv/bin/python ../../../venv/bin/celery worker --app=tasks -l debug
 | |     | |--- 06797 vng /Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/venv/bin/python ../../../venv/bin/celery worker --app=tasks -l debug
 | |     | \--- 06798 vng /Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/venv/bin/python ../../../venv/bin/celery worker --app=tasks -l debug
 | |     |--= 06782 vng memcached
 | |     \-+= 06783 vng ../../../venv/bin/python backend.py
 | |       \--- 06790 vng /Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/src/giordano/web/../../../venv/bin/python backend.py
```

killing supervisor results in:

```
^C2013-05-08 18:43:18,305 WARN received SIGINT indicating exit request
2013-05-08 18:43:18,305 INFO waiting for celeryd, memcached, backend to die
2013-05-08 18:43:18,352 INFO stopped: backend (exit status 0)
2013-05-08 18:43:18,353 INFO stopped: memcached (terminated by SIGTERM)
2013-05-08 18:43:18,414 INFO stopped: celeryd (exit status 0)
```

And out of no where, backend.py gets displaced in pstree:

```
 |--= 41659 root /usr/libexec/taskgated -s
 |--- 42779 vng /usr/local/Cellar/erlang/R15B03-1/lib/erlang/erts-5.9.3.1/bin/epmd -daemon
 |--= 88518 root /usr/sbin/ocspd
 |--- 97815 vng /Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/MacOS/Dropbox /firstrunupdate 403
 |--= 97905 _usbmuxd /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/Resources/usbmuxd -launchd
 \--- 06790 vng /Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/src/giordano/web/../../../venv/bin/python backend.py
```

I am annoyed by this because every time I restart supervisord I am getting an error that the port is already being used.

Anyone here knows what is causing this problem?

EDIT:

My backend.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'asgasdasdgasd'
app.debug = bool(int(os.environ.get("DEBUG", 1)))   # DEBUG=0
if app.debug:
  from giordano.web import colorer # Needed for coloring logging

app.config.update(
  MAIL_SERVER='smtp.gmail.com',
  MAIL_DEBUG=False,
  MAIL_PORT=465,
  MAIL_USE_SSL=True,
  MAIL_USERNAME = 'asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf@asdasdfas.com',
  MAIL_PASSWORD = 'asdfasdfasdfa'
)
mail = Mail(app)    # Very important to do it after!!

log_level = logging.DEBUG if app.debug else logging.INFO
logging.basicConfig(level=log_level, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
logging.info("Launching app with debug=%s" % app.debug)

....

class TimedRequestHandler(BaseRequestHandler):
  """http://blog.sendhub.com/post/48832423565/hacking-flask-a-success-story
  """
  def handle(self):
    self.fancyStarted = time.time()
    rv = super(TimedRequestHandler, self).handle()
    return rv

  def send_response(self, code, message=None):
    self.fancyProcessed = time.time()
    super(TimedRequestHandler, self).send_response(code, message=None)

  def log_request(self, code='-', size='-'):
    duration = int((self.fancyProcessed - self.fancyStarted) * 1000)
    line = '"{0}" {1} {2} [{3}ms]'.format(self.requestline, code, size, duration)
    self.log('info', line)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   init_db() # run if you need to create tables
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8888, request_handler=TimedRequestHandler)
```

Answer (score 1):

add `stopasgroup=true` in your configs, it should be work. this configuration will kill all the subprocess when you do `stop` or `restart`.

```
If true, the flag causes supervisor to send the stop signal to the whole process group and implies killasgroup is true. This is useful for programs, such as Flask in debug mode, that do not propagate stop signals to their children, leaving them orphaned.
```

http://supervisord.org/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you, but have you thought about using nginx to handle your port situation?  Since I believe flask runs on port 5000 by default, you could create a myapp.conf with:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    # location to your app
    root /srv/www/my_app;

    # Don't forget to create log files
    access_log /srv/www/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/logs/error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
}
```

Put that config in both "sites-available" and "sites-enabled," or  sym link it with `ln -s /srv/www/my_app/nginx/my_app.conf /etc/nginx/<sites-available>`

The application directories are completely arbitrary, but it is worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I temporarily pushed a flask app up using werkzeug with auto-reload enabled, similar to what you're doing, and disabling the auto-reload feature solved the problem. You really should just use uwsgi to handle your flask app and run that in supervisor instead. You can setup uwsgi to auto-reload the app much the same way as werkzeug.

Here's a rough guide: http://flaviusim.com/blog/Deploying-Flask-with-nginx-uWSGI-and-Supervisor/

You might also have better luck just changing your stopsignal in supervisor too...

Also, you could try using werkzeug in fastcgi mode: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/deployment/fastcgi/